# Сравнение строк в JS

Tags: строки, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить возникшую проблему:

В js Сравниваю 2 строки одинакового содержания:
1 строка "Y" - приходит как ответ сервера на ajax запрос;
2 строка тоже "Y" как переменная в скрипте, который принимает запрос.

Оба значения точно строки `typeof() - string`, значения строк визуально одинаковы!
Но при сравнении выдают false!
Проблема в том, что 1 строка("Y").length = 3 (то, что приходит с сервера).
2 строка("Y").length = 1 (переменная).

Как их сравнить в true? С сервера приходит строка со скрытыми символами юникода? Как этого избежать или как ее обработать?

Answer (score 1):

```
myServerString.trim( ) == "Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

это, скорее всего, "Y\r\n", но хорошо бы посмотреть на код - что приходит, как сравнивается...